# clear_costamps recovery clear only one layer

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to configure the clear costmaps recovery to only clear one specific layer in both?

I found the following question in the forum here but cant get it to work. I don't even know howto set up all the requiered parameters for the recovery behaviours and can't find any documenation about it.
https://answers.ros.org/question/252530/static-global-map-updating/

I would appreciate any help and ideas,
thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371713/clear_costamps-recovery-clear-only-one-layer/) by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on ROS Answers with karma: 220 on 2021-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation for recovery behaviors is in the [`move_base` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#Parameters).  Basically, you just list the plugins you want to use, and since you specifically mention `clear_costmap_recovery`, we'll go with that.  I agree the [`clear_costmap_recovery` documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/clear_costmap_recovery) isn't the most informative, but you can get a look at the plugin's parameters by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/noetic-devel/clear_costmap_recovery/src/clear_costmap_recovery.cpp).  [This line](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/7f22997e6804d9d7249b8a1d789bf27343b26f75/clear_costmap_recovery/src/clear_costmap_recovery.cpp#L75) indicates the most relevant parameter to your question, `layer_names`:

```
private_nh.param("layer_names", clearable_layers, clearable_layers_default);
```

This code is a plugin to `move_base`, so it's parameters are set through that node.  Here's an example of how I might set this recovery behavior's parameters in `move_base_params.yaml`:

```
recovery_behaviors:
  - name: costmap_reset
    type: clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery

costmap_reset:
  reset_distance: 0.0
  layer_names: ["my_layer"]
```

I set the `recovery_behaviors` parameter of the `move_base` node to a single-item list (sequence), where the item is indicated by the dash.  Note that in the `move_base` wiki, it shows the default value as an bracketed list (flow style); this is simply a different syntax for the same type of [YAML collection](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963).  I name the the specific recovery behavior "costmap_reset," and indicate its type.  To change its parameters, I define them under its namespace (same as the behavior name) on the same level as `recover_behaviors`.  I tell the plugin to only clear `my_layer` by giving the `layer_names` parameter single-item sequence of strings.  The actual definition of `my_layer` is something that happens in the [costmap](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d) configuration files (see the question you linked), but you can reference those layers here since the `move_base` node handles all of it.

If you've tried this, and it's not working, please clarify what happens (errors, warnings, behavior, etc.) and post your own files and output for troubleshooting.

---

###Update

> i am not sure if it makes a difference when its triggered via rosservice call or move_base directly

The `clear_costmaps` service and recovery behavior are separate.  The service resets all layers and doesn't take parameters, so that's not something you can change without modifying the [source code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/7f22997e6804d9d7249b8a1d789bf27343b26f75/move_base/src/move_base.cpp#L339):

```
bool MoveBase::clearCostmapsService(std_srvs::Empty::Request &req, std_srvs::Empty::Response &resp){
  //clear the costmaps
  boost::unique_lock<costmap_2d::Costmap2D::mutex_t> lock_controller(*(controller_costmap_ros_->getCostmap()->getMutex()));
  controller_costmap_ros_->resetLayers();

  boost::unique_lock<costmap_2d::Costmap2D::mutex_t> lock_planner(*(planner_costmap_ros_->getCostmap()->getMutex()));
  planner_costmap_ros_->resetLayers();
  return true;
}
```

The service simply calls `resetLayers()` for both the local (`controller_costmap_ros_`) and global (`planner_costmap_ros_`) costmaps.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-02-13**:
Hey man,

thanks for your intuitive answer.
I want to clear my custom layer with the recovery and trigger the recovery manually, not only when move_base doesn't find a valid path.

I configured it like your suggestion and triggered the service via the terminal using rosservice call ...
(i am not sure if it makes a difference when its triggered via rosservice call or move_base directly).

```
recovery_behaviors:
```

- name: 'costmap_reset_conservative'
  type: 'clear_costmap_recovery/ClearCostmapRecovery'

costmap_reset_conservative:
reset_distance: 1.5
layer_names: ["my"]

with my layer configuration beeing:

```
my:
```

enabled: true

The only problem i got with this, is that it has cleared every layer, not only my custom one.
To solve this i just implemented a service in the source code of my custom layer which sets every cell of the layer to 0. This seems to work quiet nicely so i wont spend more time trying to abuse the recovery behaviour by triggering it myself.

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-02-13**:
not sure why the formating is messed up sorry

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-02-13**:
Ah, I see.  The service is separate from the recovery behaviors and resets all layers, so your approach with a custom service is the way to go.  I updated my answer with some more information.

The code format just adds 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, but sometimes multiple lines come out weird.  If you add the spaces manually (plus indentation), it should come out right.

**Comment by [Tristan9497](https://answers.ros.org/users/62795/tristan9497/) on 2021-02-13**:
Ah, ok that makes sense i should have clarified that at the start of my question...
But i guess it's nice to have that information now atleast here at answers.ros for future readers

Thanks for the tip with the formating aswell, ill try to fix that :)